# Transformer in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Could you help me with drawing of the transformer (see below)? I haven't enough experience with `circuitikz` library, and at this point it seems that this block isn't part of `circuitikz` double dipoles (it might be un usual way of drawing transformer)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you already have, i.e. bake an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), such that people can find an answer that really helps you.

Comment: Circuitikz already has 3 different transfomers (6 if you add cores).  I did find a version similar to yours at https://www.daenotes.com/electronics/basic-electronics/transformer

Comment: Jusr out of interrest: in what language do you write your document? Because in Dutch books we use the American transformer, not the European one.

Comment: My document is written in French, so we have this symbol (and alsothe other one of LaTeX) of the transformer. As far as I know the two symbols are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can always do is to look up a definition of a resembling element, copy its definition to the preamble of your TeX file and modify it. Here is an example, based on the `gyrator` shape. I stress that I have no knowledge on circuitiz other than that its based on Ti*k*Z, and I also have no practical knowledge about circuits, which I successfully avoided to learn ;-).

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarequadpole{my transformer}{

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.8\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6\pgf@circ@res@left}{0.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpatharc{-45}{315}{0.6\pgf@circ@res@down}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.8\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.61\pgf@circ@res@left}{0.43\pgf@circ@res@down}}


    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.8\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.6\pgf@circ@res@right}{0.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpatharc{225}{-135}{0.6\pgf@circ@res@down}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.8\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.61\pgf@circ@res@right}{0.43\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0.6\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0.6\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0.6\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0.6\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.8\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.8\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
}{}

\makeatother    
\ctikzset{quadpoles/my transformer/width/.initial=1.5}
\ctikzset{quadpoles/my transformer/height/.initial=1}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw  node[my transformer,anchor=north west] (my trafo){}
node[anchor=east]  at (my trafo.west){$V_1$}
node[anchor=west]  at (my trafo.east){$V_2$}
node[anchor=south]  at (my trafo.north west){$I_1$}
node[anchor=south]  at (my trafo.north east){$I_2$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you, it works really well (for someone who have the chance to avoid circuits and `circuitikz`)

Answer (score 3):

You can combine elements of the package to create new ones, according to my example for the [TL431 component](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426294/154390), you can define a new component, mixing the circuitikz macros and drawings with Tikz code, definig a macro under the scope structure, you can name the coordinates of the terminals of the components and add them an identifier, that way you can use as many as you want and connect them using the names of their terminals, here an example, the circuit is just to test the connections, it has no electrical design criteria.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
% By J. Leon V.  coded based on the BSD, MIT, Beerware licences.
\documentclass[border=30pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm} % to navoid modify text sizes and separations.
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

% Creating new electronic part
 \def\TL431(#1)#2{%#1: Position #2: Identifier.
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}] % using to make coordinate objet.
    \draw(0,0) coordinate (A) coordinate (A #2)  %set this coordinate as anode
    to [sD*,-](0,2) coordinate (B) coordinate (K #2); % set this coordinate to kathode (sD* is circuittikz objet)
    \coordinate (C) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$); % Find the center point between A and B
    \coordinate (D) at ($(A)!1!90:(C)$); % find a point orthogonal. 
    \node at (C) [rectangle, minimum size=7mm,draw=black,thick] {};%put the rectangle.
    \draw (C) -- +(D) coordinate (R #2);% draw the Vref pin and set tho coordinate Ref
    % Set the labels
    \draw (0,0.5) node[right] {\scriptsize A};
    \draw (0,1.5) node[right] {\scriptsize K};
    \draw (-.7,0.8) node[right] {\scriptsize R};
    \draw (.4,1) node[right] {\small D - #2}; % Diode label identifier
  \end{scope}
}

% Creating new electric component
 \def\Trafo(#1)#2{%#1: Position#2: Identifier.
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}] % using to make coordinate objet.
    % Terminal P1-identifier
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (P1-#2) to [short,o-,i=$i_{1-#2}$] (0.5,0);
    \draw (.5,0) -- ++(.25,-.6); % Wire
    \draw (1.2,-1) circle (6mm); % Primary
    \draw (0.5,-2) -- ++(.25,.6);% Wire
    % Terminal P2-identifier
    \draw (0,-2) coordinate (P2-#2) to [short,o-] (0.5,-2);
    % Terminal s1-identifier
    \draw (3,0)  coordinate (S1-#2) to [short,o-,i_<=$i_{2-#2}$] (2.5,0);
    \draw (2.5,0) -- ++(-.25,-.6); %Wire
    \draw (1.8,-1) circle (6mm); % Secondary
    \draw (2.5,-2) -- ++(-.25,.6); %Wire
    % Terminal S2-identifier
    \draw (3,-2) coordinate (S2-#2) to [short,o-] (2.5,-2);
    \draw (1.5,0) node[] {\small T - #2}; % Trafo label identifier
    \draw (P1-#2) to [open, v_<=$V_{P-#2}$] (P2-#2); % Primary voltage
    \draw (S1-#2) to [open, v^<=$V_{S-#2}$] (S2-#2); % Secondary voltaje
  \end{scope}
}


 %Drawing first line input - R 
 \draw (0,0) 
    node [anchor=east]{Input}
    to[R,o-*](2,0);
% Insert TL431 in position 2,-3 and identified as 1
\TL431(2,-3){1};

% Conect first line and TL431 
\draw
    (2,0) to [short,-*] (K 1); % K 1 is the identified coordinate kathode

% Conect TL431 to ground % A 1 is the identified coordinate of anode
\draw (A 1) to (2,-5.5) coordinate (GND) node [ground]{};

%Draw the close loop between Ref and kathode
\draw[-] (R 1) |- (K 1);

%Draw the Vref 
\draw (R 1) 
    to [short, -o] (1,-3.5)
    to [open,v=Vref] (1,-4.5)
    to [short, o-] (1,-5.5) node[ground]{};

% Drawing the trafos
\Trafo(4.5,0){1}
\Trafo(4.5,-3){2}

% Conecting the trafos
\draw (2,0) to [R,-] (P1-1);
\draw (P2-1) -- ++(-0.3,0) |- (P1-2);
\draw (P2-2)
    to [short,-*] (P2-2 -| GND);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```