# Create transfomer symbol consisting of two circles

Tags: shapes, circuits

I am drawing a simple power system in a single line diagram and want to define a shape for a transformer, which looks like two partly overlapping circles. I have already defined styles for generators and impedances using \tikzset. By doing this I can easily draw generators and impedances using the node command. However, I haven't figured out how to do this for the transformer as it consists of two circles not one. Does anyone know an easy way to define this transformer shape, such that I can easily create one with the the node command?

[image: Transformer symbol]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! To draw the above figure, you can use very simple TikZ command `\draw (0,0) circle (1cm); \draw (0,1) circle (1cm);` but please explain more about the size of the shape, how you use the shape, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Your solution is how I do it now, but I was wondering how to define a style for this. I have added more details in my question now.

Comment: It sounds like you should take a look at `circuitikz`. Then you can do e.g. `\draw (0,0) to[ioosource] (0,2);`

Comment: Hi, the circuittikz also works :) Many thanks.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431334/transformer-in-circuitikz

Comment: @John Kormylo. Thanks that's also an interesting circuitikz shape, however, it would not work that well for drawing a single line diagram. I guess I should have been more specific. I will update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for` loop is an answer for you here:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


    \tikzset{
        mycirc/.pic={
            \foreach \w in {0,1} {
                \draw (0,\w) circle (1cm);
            }
        }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (2,2) {mycirc};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which will give you:

[image]

Even you can change the design choices of your transformers:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


    \tikzset{
        main/.style ={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.6cm, dashed},
        mycirc/.pic={
            \foreach \w in {0,1} {
                \draw[main] (0,\w) circle (1cm);
            }
        }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (2,2) {mycirc};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which will give you:

[image]

Comment: Hi, many thanks. Your solution looks exactly, like what I was thinking about. One question. Is it possible to change your code such that I can draw the shape using the following command: 
`\node[mycirc] (pos) {};`.
 For the generator shape I get this behavior, when I write `.style` where you have written `.pic`.

Comment: @SigurdHofsmoJakobsen It will not work (I think), because, it is not a style instead it is a picture ;) But if you want to draw it with `mypic` then you need to define a custom `macro` for that purpose (which is out-of-scope of this question here :D). [off-topic] IMHO, it is an over-kill :D

Comment: Ok, many thanks. 
Yes, I don't want to define a custom macro, it does seem a bit overkill ;P. Anyway, your proposal work fine for my purpose :)

Comment: Ofc, I just didn't know it was a button for that.

Comment: No problems, now you know :) Happy `TeXing` :D or must I say `TikZing` :D